# How to get regex value from $httpBackend whenGET

Tags: regex, angularjs, httpbackend

```
  $httpBackend.whenGET(/api\/product\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}/).respond(function(data) {
      // Code to find given ID in collection
  });
```

When I call this endpoint, I should return the product that matches the given product ID (the regex value). How do I access this value? The data value just equals 'GET'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using $httpBackend in a unit test. If that's so, you have two options. You can choose to use respond to define custom responses (which is what you are doing above).

**Or** you could use the passThrough method, which should actually call the API (which then makes your tests slightly more volatile as they are not self-reliant, a service interruption could cause the test to fail).

You can read about the .get (including whenGET) and .passThrough methods on the [AngularJS $httpBackend documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend).

**EDIT**

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/api\/product\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}/)
    .respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
        /** do something with url */
    });
```

Comment: At the moment I'm actually using it as a placeholder for the APIs I'm calling, since they're being developed in parallel. So I need a way to use the value being passed as the regex to find the correct product ID.

Comment: Got it. I'm pretty sure you can get that in the second argument of the .respond method. I will update updated my answer for reference. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to grab the URL and slice it from there.